# How to escape $ in the variable name in django

Tags: django, django-templates

In my code variable name named data contain dict with name 'username' and 'user$id'

if i do {{ data.username }} everything is ok.
but if i do {{ data.user$id }} nothing is shown.

how do escape $ to make Django template work?

Comment: That sounds strange. Did you put the dollar symbol in there? Can you take it out? Are you sure it's really a dollar symbol - have you tried {{ data.user.id }}.

Comment: Not sure if this typo is in your original code, but you have the wrong brackets. {[ data.user$id }} should be {{ data.user$id }}.

Comment: are yar lokesh ye kya post kiye ho ku $ beech me use ker rahe ho what does that mean i never found a django like this

Comment: @JackShedd you are right this is typo.

Comment: @masterofdestiny this is the response by youtube api.youtube uses $ if format is json. Why would i use $ in variable name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Template does not allow of dollor character to be inside variable name, [ref the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/#variables):

> Variable names consist of any combination of alphanumeric characters and the underscore ("_"). The dot (".") also appears...

In Django shell

```
>>> from django.template import *
>>> Template("{{ data.user$id }}").render(Context({'data':{'user$id':'foo'}}))
...
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '$id' from 'data.user$id'

# "{[" also does not work
>>> Template("{[ data.user$id }}").render(Context({'data':{'user$id':'foo'}}))
u'{[ data.user$id }}'
```

Thus you need to represent the key explicitly as a string

```
{% for k, v in data.iteritems %}
    {% if k == 'user$id' %}{{ v }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or write a template tag which works as `{% get_value data "user$id" %}`

Comment: Approach one will kill me. As this is response from the YouTube (format=json). I go with approach Two.Thanks